# What is the meaning of "${name##*/}" in Shell

Tags: shell, shell-script, ksh, aix

I have a code as

```
while read name; do uuencode "$name" "${name##*/}"; done
```

but I do not understand what is meaning of `##*/` in `"${name##*/}"`

Google doesn't give good results. Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used to get the filename from the full path. This is similar to using the `basename` command.

Example:

```
filename="/tmp/test.txt"
echo "$filename" "${filename##*/}"
/tmp/test.txt test.txt
basename "$filename"
test.txt``
```